# kotlin serialization return null

Tags: android, kotlin, json-deserialization

I have a problem with serializing data on response to an api call.
It's my first time using this.
Service is called with "Retrofit" and everything goes well, the logs report the request and the response exactly.
Al network is into `NetworModule`

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(
            HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            }
        )
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val httpUrl: HttpUrl = chain.request().url.newBuilder().build()
            val request: Request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(httpUrl).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

    @Provides
    fun provideApiNetwork(retrofit: Retrofit): RetrofitApiNetwork =
        retrofit.create(RetrofitApiNetwork::class.java)
}
```

response in json is:

```json
{
    "response": {
        "info": {
            ...
        },
        "body": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

the problem comes in constructing a generic model with generic type.
Interface of calls:

```kotlin
interface RetrofitApiNetwork {

    @GET("....")
    suspend fun getElements(): APINetworkResponse<Element>
}
```

Generic models is:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class APINetworkResponse<T>(
   val response: Response<T>
)

@Serializable
data class Response<T>(
     val info: Info,
     val body: T
)
```

The value of `APINetworkResponse<Element>` is `APINetworkResponse(response=null)`

Can someone help me understand why and give me the solution. Thanks

**Update**
add repository:

```kotlin
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val retrofitApiNetwork: RetrofitApiNetwork
){

    suspend fun getArtistChart(): Flow<Element> = flow {
        val apiNetworkResponse: APINetworkResponse<Element> = retrofitApiNetwork.getElements()
        println(apiNetworkResponse) /*APINetworkResponse(response=null)*/
    }
}
```

add dependecies:

```ini
[versions]
androidGradlePlugin = "7.3.1"
kotlin = "1.7.10"
kotlinDsl = "2.3.3"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitExt = "1.1.4"
testCore = "1.5.0"
espresso = "3.5.0"
coreKtx = "1.9.0"
appcompat = "1.5.1"
material = "1.7.0"
retrofit = "2.9.0"
hilt = "2.44.2"
nav = "2.5.3"

[libraries]
android-pluginGradle = { group = "com.android.tools.build", name = "gradle", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
kotlin-pluginGradle = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlin" }

junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitExt" }
espresso = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espresso" }
androidx-test-core = { group = "androidx.test", name = "core", version.ref = "testCore" }
androidx-test-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.test", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "testCore" }

androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }

appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }

android-material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }

android-retrofit = { group = "com.squareup.retrofit2", name = "retrofit", version.ref = "retrofit" }
android-retrofit-converter = { group = "com.squareup.retrofit2", name = "converter-gson", version.ref = "retrofit" }

android-navigation = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment", version.ref = "nav" }
android-navigation-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "nav" }
android-navigation-ui-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "nav" }

android-hilt = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
android-hilt-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
android-library = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
kotlin-jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-dsl = { id = "org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl", version.ref = "kotlinDsl" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }
```

````
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    ```
````

Comment: I don't see the kotlinx-serialization converter factory. https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter

Comment: hi lionel have added the factory but didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the answers were successful. I fixed it by adding rules to the application proguard-rules file.
I followed [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#android) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `suspend` function to get the results using Coroutines, so make sure you have these dependencies on your project:

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
```

*Check for the latest versions, I'm using 1.6.4 at the time of writing this response.*

Without these dependencies, Retrofit doesn't know about transforming a coroutine function and when the code is compiled, the mapper is unaware of the models because of the suspend function.

Comment: this didn't help

Comment: Share the dependencies you are using ..

Comment: shared toml file

Comment: did you try converting the gradle version to toml version of dependencies? I checked the only dependencies missing are the ones I shared.

Comment: yes, your implementation are added into dependecies section of gradle file

Comment: Did you try removing the `suspend` keyword from the retrofit service? You are using a flow, so you don't need a `suspend` if you are not going to emit or collect from the repository. If you remove the suspend and it works, so it is definitely the dependencies.

Comment: if remove the suspend i have this exeption `E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for APINetworkResponse<Element>.`

Comment: Did you configure the GsonAdapter in the RetrofitBuilder? `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

Comment: why should i use gson if i'm using kotlin library for serialization?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the data keyword when defining the classes which creates the component1(), component2(), etc. automatically, but those functions do not support generics.

Instead, you should use the @Serializable annotation on the class, and use @SerialName on the variables.

Try changing your classes to this:

```
@Serializable
class APINetworkResponse<T> (
    @SerialName("response") val response: Response<T>
)

@Serializable
class Response<T> (
    @SerialName("info") val info: Info,
    @SerialName("body") val body: T
)
```

Also, you should make sure that the Element class is serializable. You can use the @Serializable annotation on it too.

Comment: this didn't help